# Editing an XML object - Connection Strings

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML config loaded into my script as an xml object called `$appConfig`. I am trying to replace the connection string value with a string of my own. This is what I have so far which finds the target string:

```psh
$appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add |
    ? {$_.name -eq $dbName} |
    select connectionString
```

I essentially want something akin to this:

```psh
$appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add |
    ? {$_.name -eq $dbName} |
    select connectionString = $updatedConnectionString
```

I'm pretty sure I need to make a variable and populate it with the `$appConfig` but everytime I try I just end up with another XML object instead of editing the target `$appConfig` object as intended. I write the `$appConfig` back to its original file location and complete the edit. I just can't seem to get the right syntax here.

My XML example related to the strings:

```xml
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="dbFiles" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="dbReporting" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Logging" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's 4 elements with a `connectionString` attribute in there. Which of them do you want to change, and which new value do you want to assign to them?

Comment: Well the $dbName variable defines the target this is passed to the function I chose not to include it because the variable shifts with the name values. So if I figure on an answer for 1 I get the answer to change any of them.

Comment: Further to your last; I am only attempting to replace the "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" with a string. However, I want to try to do this as an xml object and not just string replace as different configs would make this process difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use dot-notation, you could do something like this:

```
$node = $appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add |
        Where-Object {$_.name -eq $dbName}
$node.connectionString = $updatedConnectionString
$appConfig.Save()
```

or like this (if you don't want to assign the selected node to a variable before modifying its attribute):

```
($appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $dbName}).connectionString = $updatedConnectionString
$appConfig.Save()
```

Another way would be to use the `SelectSingleNode()` method with an XPath expression, e.g. like this:

```
($appConfig.SelectSingleNode("//add[@name='$dbName']").connectionString = $updatedConnectionString
$appConfig.Save()
```