# How to Find String in File(s) and Replace a Unknown Number of Characters After It?

Tags: powershell, substring, str-replace

#### Problem

I am trying to write a complex find and replace method with the purpose of recursively searching a directory (provided by the user) for all config files and replace a select set of sections/keys within the config files based on whether or not a series of check boxes are checked.

#### Expected Results/Example

In the scenario below, I only want to replace the database password with a new value (thus the other values are not important for this example).

```
# collect only the configs that contain the section/key names the application is designed to alter
$configs = GCI -Path "$somePath\*.config" -Recurse | Where-Object {
    ((Select-String -Pattern "DatabasePassword") -ceq $true) -OR
    ((Select-String -Pattern "SomeKey02") -ceq $true) -OR
    ((Select-String -Pattern "SomeKey03") -ceq $true)
}

# if the checkbox for Database Password is checked, get the text after its key
if (DBPassword.Checked) {
    foreach ($configFile in $configFiles) {
        GC $configFile | Foreach-Object {
            if ($config -match "DatabasePassword") {
                #I know this next part is sorta right, but I haven't been able to get it to work right
                $tmpStr = $configfile | Out-String
                $start = tmpStr.IndexOf("=") + 2
                $end = $tmpStr.IndexOf('"', $start)
                $length = $end - $start

                $Pass2Replace = $tmpStr.Substring($start, $length)                    
            }
        }
    }
}

# This Next Section is Contained Within a ForEach Loop
# I believe I am Close, but This Doesn't Quite Work
# Parse Through All Config Files and Replace Keys Based On the '.Checked' Status of Each Check Box
(GC $configFiles) | ForEach-Object {
    if ($DBPassword.Checked) {
        ForEach-Object { $_.Replace($Pass2Replace, $newPass.Text) } 
    if ($checkbox02.Checked) {
        ForEach-Object { $_.Replace($Key2Replace02, $newStr02.Text) }
    if ($checkBox03.Checked) {
        ForEach-Object { $_.Replace($Key2Replace03, $newStr03.Text) }
}
# Save Changes
Set-Content $configFile
```

So ultimately, what I would have expected to have happened is that the User would have checked the "Update Password" checkbox, entered a new password in the GUI textbox, and clicked on the "Update" button. Then, the application would seek out the config files, look for the key `DatabasePassword`, modify the the stored value, and save the changes. Below is a simplified version of this paragraph:

Before:

```
DatabasePassword = "SomeEncryptedPassword"
```

After:

```
DatabasePassword = "AlteredEncryptedPassword"
```

#### Questions

**Primary Question:** What is the best way to get PowerShell to collect the unknown stored value of these keys and replace ONLY that value?

Sub Question 01: Assuming the Primary Question has an answer, is it possible to collect only a portion of the stored value and replace that?

example: Say I have a key called `ConnectionString` with a value of `((someRandomValue=AWQagaWGAAE#!)(someSetOfStrings))` ; howeverver, I only want to collect the `(someRandomValue=AWQagaWGAAE#!)` section of the value. How would I collect only this portion and replace it (please keep in mind that the someRandomValue is an unknown)?

Comment: Please show some sample before and after text. Regex will simplify this greatly. Need concreate examples however.

Comment: @Matt I modified the post to include a more related example and what I would have expected to be changed

Comment: What is the structure of your .config files? Flat text? INI style? XML?

Comment: Side note: the syntax of your last code section is broken. `if` statements neither read from nor do they write to the pipeline.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: 1) XML based, 2) Well, there is something I was not aware... is there a way to achieve a similar effect without creating multiple variants of the pipeline?

Comment: For XML files I recommend using an actual XML parser. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687802/1630171).

Comment: well the config files are just that .configs like Web.Config / App.Config, so I don't think an XML Parser would work with that. I think I may have misunderstood your earlier comment.

Comment: *"so I don't think an XML Parser would work with that."* You think wrong.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Well thank you for "clearing that up". Now since the original question was "how do I do this in PowerShell", do you by chance have an answer that would resolve the above problems? In the meantime, I will do what research I can on a parser that I can utilize with PowerShell.

Comment: I have good news, PowerShell *is* an XML parser! `[xml]$MyConfig = GC $ConfigPath` reads in the file as XML. You can then pipe that to `Select-Xml` to perform XPath searches and what not, or if the path to the various keys is known already you can just do things like `$OldDBPass = $MyConfig.Settings.DB1.DatabasePassword` and `$MyConfig.Settings.DB1.DatabasePassword = $NewPass`, and then `$MyConfig.Save()` to apply the updates.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That's actually fantastic to hear. I was reading a little on this earlier prior to seeing this. But one thing I don't fully understand how to apply this to an array. I assume that I would call each section in terms of parent->child->etc until I reach the item I want?

Comment: An array of what? Of files? Of settings?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician To clarify, I am creating an array of .configs. I then want to parse through each file one-by-one. As I parse through them, I want to test a series of conditional statements and update the file based on the pass or fail of those statements. Then save the results. What would be the best approach to that using this feature?

Comment: "How do I get the substring, how do I search matching files, how do I remove multiple charactes, how do I use the pipeline with `if`, how do I process XML, how do I deal with multiple files" ... close-voting as too broad for the reason "*Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.*"

Answer (score 0):

No answer yet, I'd like post one. I don't quite catch your question, but I think I can solve your essential requirements by **3 command lines**.

According to your code snippet, seems you're in `Powershell` environment, and you're recursively searching and updating in directory `$somepath` with `*.config` files.

So, brief to your answer to update `DatabasePassword`:

`` if ($DBPassword.Checked) {
    msr.exe -r -p $somepath -f "\.config$" -it "(DatabasePassword)\s*=\s*\S+" -o "`$1 = $newPass.Text" -R
} ``

And the same for updating `Key2Replace02` `Key2Replace03`. So you probably just need 3 `if` and replacing command lines .
You can preview replacing without `-R`, backup with `-K`;

See **msr.exe** in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory.

You can add some options of `msr.exe` , such as `--nd "^(target|bin|\.git|\.svn|obj)$"`, just run `msr.exe` or the doc site like: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html
(You'll find it supper fast after first time searching/reading files)

Comment: Thank you for this potential answer to my question. Is this `msr.exe` something I will need to install/download, or is it already a part of PowerShell? Due to the limitations of my work environment, I cannot download/install any software/add-on without seeking approval first.

Comment: It's just a single exe file, no dependency. but, .., you should download it like: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/tools/msr.exe?raw=true -OutFile $your-dir\msr.exe` :)